# How to copy value of a SharePoint column to another column in same list

Tags: 2010, calculated-column-formula

I have a form which contains a column "DGM" of type "people". There is another column "Approver" which I need to be auto populated with the same value as DGM contains. I tried using the formula =[DGM] in calculated value of Approver column. But I am getting following error:

```
One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas.
```

I don't have SharePoint Designer so have to accomplish the task through UI. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the Column that needs to get the value a calculated field instead of a text field, then add the =[DGM] to the Formula.

You can select calculated from the radio buttons which have all types of fields.

Calculated Value in a "single line of text" field is only for "Me" or "Today"